# Web and Mobile Analytics

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am setting up Web and Mobile Analytics on our site using ET's out of the box solution.

I've put it on a site where I see some traffic, but I can't find where the resulting data is stored, i.e., I want to see from a subscriber level what pages they viewed or how long they staying on the site, where/how can I access this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reporting can be found here:

[image: Web and Mobile Analytics]

Answer (score 1):

You can ask support to enable an integration between Web & Mobile Analytics and data extensions in Marketing Cloud, allowing you to get an even more detailed view on the behaviour of the individual visitor, and also use this data for segmenting identified visitors.

Comment: really? It seems like this would be a partner paid thing to do. Does this already exist?

Comment: @garek007 since few releases ago, this is now self service. This feature can be accessed and enabled within settings, when configuring Einstein Recommendations on MC

Comment: cool thanks it's great to be able to do it without having to open a ticket